# Jest React: Test if function has been called on blur event

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a react component:

```
 class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  getInput(e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    localStorage.setItem('searchValue', e.target.value);
  }
  render() {
    const value = localStorage.getItem('searchValue') ? localStorage.getItem('searchValue') : '';
    return (
      <section className="section_search-bar">
        <TextField
          fullWidth
          id="outlined-helperText"
          label="Search"
          defaultValue={`${value}`}
          onBlur={this.getInput}
          type={'search'}
        />
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to test if function has been called on blur event. As I understood I need to use jest.spyOn, but maybe I don't use it correct?

```
test('search bar focus out', () => {
    render(<SearchBar />);
    const input = screen.getByLabelText('Search');
    const onBlurSpy = jest.spyOn(input, 'blur');
    fireEvent.blur(input);
    expect(onBlurSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Because I have a mistake:

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Test what the `onBlur` _does_ - if the input has a value, does that get set in local storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to test is the expected behaviour of the component. So in this case as @jonrsharpe wrote check if an expected value is set in local storage. Or spyOn the `setItem` method to check if it was called with correct parameters.

You can try something like this:

```js
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import SearchBar from '../SearchBar';

it("should work", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup()
  render(<SearchBar />);
  const spy = jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'setItem');
  const input = screen.getByLabelText('Search');
  await user.type(input, "Testing");
  await user.tab() // blur
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("searchValue", "Testing")
});
```